# Calculated field: How to calculate the sum of fieldvalues of all referencing entities

Tags: entities

Using Drupal 7.43
Using ECK entities.

This question is based on my attempt to create a simple bookkeeping system in Drupal, in which I have Account entites and Expense entities.
The Expense entities reference an Account in an entity reference field.

The Account entity has a calculated field that should show the sum of the 'Price' fields in the referencing Expense entities.

I could accomplish this with Rules but prefer to keep reduce the administration of such complex rules.

Please assist in setting up the calculated field code for this purpose. Thank you.

Comment: Just do a for loop

Comment: Is this on the node page or in a view?

Comment: @Paul Yuri is using drupal 8. It is neither on a node it in a view. It is a calculated field in a custom entity.

Comment: @Eyal: how do **you** know what is mentioned nowhere by **Yuri** in the title, the question, or any of its comments ?????????

Comment: @Yuri : which release of Drupal is this about?

Comment: Sorry, I inserted now the drupal version.

Comment: Using custom entities (ECK) so this is about calculated field values.

Comment: @Paul oops, my bad.